# TCP server on ESP32 CAM

Tags: esp32, esp32-cam

I am writing a TCP server on ESP32 CAM to receive joystick coordinates as a JSON string. I have a TCP client on my laptop which sends joystick coordinates from a joystick connected to my laptop. In have implemented a 0.8 second throttling on the client side, such that JSON strings are only sent 0.8 seconds apart. When I test this, I am able to run the joystick reliably for about a minute before the ESP crashes due to a Guru Meditation Error.

This is the exception I get:

```
Guru Meditation Error: Core  0 panic'ed (IllegalInstruction). Exception was unhandled.
Memory dump at 0x4016797c: c00289c0 f01d0020 40004136
Core  0 register dump:
PC      : 0x40167980  PS      : 0x00060030  A0      : 0x40105dff  A1      : 0x3ffbc110  
A2      : 0x00000002  A3      : 0x00000011  A4      : 0x3ffbe0d4  A5      : 0x00000000  
A6      : 0x3ffbc13c  A7      : 0x0000005d  A8      : 0x80084f78  A9      : 0x3ffbc0f0  
A10     : 0x00000001  A11     : 0x00000000  A12     : 0x00000000  A13     : 0x3ff42034  
A14     : 0x0000001e  A15     : 0xfffffffe  SAR     : 0x00000017  EXCCAUSE: 0x00000000  
EXCVADDR: 0x00000000  LBEG    : 0x4008a674  LEND    : 0x4008a690  LCOUNT  : 0xffffffff  


Backtrace: 0x4016797d:0x3ffbc110 0x40105dfc:0x3ffbc180 0x400d5fd8:0x3ffbc1a0 0x400d5f21:0x3ffbc1c0 0x400d6a8e:0x3ffbc1f0 0x4016f10b:0x3ffbc220
```

This is my stack trace:

```
PC: 0x40167980: sub32 at /Users/ficeto/Desktop/ESP32/ESP32S2/esp-idf-public/components/mbedtls/mbedtls/library/ecp_curves.c line 980
EXCVADDR: 0x00000000

Decoding stack results
0x4016797d: sub32 at /Users/ficeto/Desktop/ESP32/ESP32S2/esp-idf-public/components/mbedtls/mbedtls/library/ecp_curves.c line 979
0x40105dfc: psram_cmd_end at /Users/ficeto/Desktop/ESP32/ESP32S2/esp-idf-public/components/esp_hw_support/port/esp32/spiram_psram.c line 385
0x400d5fd8: psramInit at C:\Users\ikibf\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\hardware\esp32\2.0.11\cores\esp32\esp32-hal-psram.c line 69
0x400d5f21: initArduino at C:\Users\ikibf\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\hardware\esp32\2.0.11\cores\esp32\esp32-hal-misc.c line 240
0x400d6a8e: app_main() at C:\Users\ikibf\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\hardware\esp32\2.0.11\cores\esp32\main.cpp line 70
0x4016f10b: main_task at /Users/ficeto/Desktop/ESP32/ESP32S2/esp-idf-public/components/freertos/port/port_common.c line 141
```

Sometimes I get this exception:

```
rst:0xc (SW_CPU_RESET),boot:0x13 (SPI_FAST_FLASH_BOOT)
configsip: 0, SPIWP:0xee
clk_drv:0x00,q_drv:0x00,d_drv:0x00,cs0_drv:0x00,hd_drv:0x00,wp_drv:0x00
mode:DIO, clock div:1
load:0x3fff0030,len:1344
load:0x40078000,len:13964
load:0x40080400,len:3600
entry 0x400805f0
Guru Meditation Error: Core  0 panic'ed (LoadProhibited). Exception was unhandled.

Core  0 register dump:
PC      : 0x401061a9  PS      : 0x00060030  A0      : 0x80085042  A1      : 0x3ffbc0f0  
A2      : 0x00000001  A3      : 0x00000000  A4      : 0x0ffd114c  A5      : 0x00000000  
A6      : 0x0000001e  A7      : 0xfffffffe  A8      : 0x00020000  A9      : 0x3ff44024  
A10     : 0x700000eb  A11     : 0x00000000  A12     : 0x00000008  A13     : 0x3ffbc0cc  
A14     : 0xb7a8d869  A15     : 0x3ff42080  SAR     : 0x0000000f  EXCCAUSE: 0x0000001c  
EXCVADDR: 0x00000001  LBEG    : 0x40106144  LEND    : 0x4010614d  LCOUNT  : 0x00000000  


Backtrace: 0x401061a6:0x3ffbc0f0 0x4008503f:0x3ffbc110 0x40105d02:0x3ffbc180 0x400d5fd8:0x3ffbc1a0 0x400d5f21:0x3ffbc1c0 0x400d6a8e:0x3ffbc1f0 0x4016f10b:0x3ffbc220
```

Which produces this stack trace:

```
PC: 0x401061a9: psram_set_cs_timing at /Users/ficeto/Desktop/ESP32/ESP32S2/esp-idf-public/components/esp_hw_support/port/esp32/spiram_psram.c line 674
EXCVADDR: 0x00000001

Decoding stack results
0x401061a6: psram_set_cs_timing at /Users/ficeto/Desktop/ESP32/ESP32S2/esp-idf-public/components/esp_hw_support/port/esp32/spiram_psram.c line 676
0x4008503f: psram_enable at /Users/ficeto/Desktop/ESP32/ESP32S2/esp-idf-public/components/esp_hw_support/port/esp32/spiram_psram.c line 998
0x40105d02: esp_spiram_init at /Users/ficeto/Desktop/ESP32/ESP32S2/esp-idf-public/components/esp_hw_support/port/esp32/spiram.c line 163
0x400d5fd8: psramInit at C:\Users\ikibf\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\hardware\esp32\2.0.11\cores\esp32\esp32-hal-psram.c line 69
0x400d5f21: initArduino at C:\Users\ikibf\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\hardware\esp32\2.0.11\cores\esp32\esp32-hal-misc.c line 240
0x400d6a8e: app_main() at C:\Users\ikibf\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\hardware\esp32\2.0.11\cores\esp32\main.cpp line 70
0x4016f10b: main_task at /Users/ficeto/Desktop/ESP32/ESP32S2/esp-idf-public/components/freertos/port/port_common.c line 141
```

This is the TCP server:

```
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiAP.h>

#include <WiFiClient.h>
#include <ArduinoJson.h>
#include "helper_funcs.h"
#include "esp_wpa2.h"  
#include "wifi_credentials.h"   // contains wifi connection params

// JSON setup stuff
const int buffer_size = 512;
char json_buffer[buffer_size];
int buffer_index = 0;

const int port = 8990;

WiFiServer server(port);

// Rest of code
void setup(){
  init_motors();

  // connect to WiFi
  Serial.begin(115200);
   WiFi.disconnect(true);
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  WiFi.begin(WIFI_SSID, WPA2_AUTH_PEAP, EAP_IDENTITY, EAP_USERNAME, EAP_PASSWORD);
  
  while(WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED){
    Serial.println("Connecting to WiFi....");
    delay(1000);
  }

  Serial.println("Connected to WiFi with IP: "); 
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

  // Start TCP/IP server
  server.begin();
  Serial.println("Started TCP/IP server");
}

void loop(){
  WiFiClient client = server.available();

  // if a client has connected to the TCP/IP server, read PWM data and use it
  if(client){
    Serial.println("Client connected");
    while(client.connected()){
      if(client.available()){
        char c = client.read();
        
        if((buffer_index != buffer_size-1) && (c != '\n')){
          json_buffer[buffer_index++] = c;  
        } else {
          // parse the JSON object
          json_buffer[buffer_index] = '\0';
          StaticJsonDocument<buffer_size> doc;  
          DeserializationError error = deserializeJson(doc, json_buffer);

          if(error){
            Serial.println("JSON parsing unsuccessful");
            Serial.println(error.c_str());  
          } else {
            // get PWM data
            int x = doc["x"], y = doc["y"];
            Serial.print("X: ");
            Serial.println(x);
            Serial.print("Y: ");
            Serial.println(y);
          
            control_motors(x, y);  
          }

          // reset JSON buffer for next data 
          buffer_index = 0;
        }
      } 
    }

    client.stop();
    Serial.println("Client disconnected");
  }
 
}
```

Does anyone know how I should solve this?

Comment: try to change the PSRAM setting in Tools menu

Comment: @Juraj I enabled PSRAM after chnaging the board to ESP Dev Module as the PSRAMoption was not available when using ESP32 Wrover Module. Unfortunately, the ESP will reboot randomly, which shuts down the server